# Quartz stop scheduled repeatative Job from 00h35 and 06h15

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a Job which runs everyday in 15 minutes but now the requirement is that we have to stop this job from `00h35 and 06h15` time .

We are using `Quartz scheduler`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the quartz scheduler but I found the documentation [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/files/documentation/Quartz-2.1.x-Documentation.pdf) and had a quick look through it. There is an example 'Build a trigger that will fire now, then repeat every five minutes, until the hour 22:00' on page 23 which sounds similar to what you want to do (starting at 06h15 and finishing at 00h35)

If it's not what you're looking for, how about putting a bit of detail in your question, specifically what you've already tried.